# Python list not appending

Tags: python

I've been following a tutorial exactly but my list isn't appending--I get the error, "AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only."

My code is:

```
mylist = [1,2,3]
mylist.append = (4)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `mylist.append(4)`

Comment: do  mylist.append(4) instead of giving value to function object.

Answer (score 3):

```
mylist = [1,2,3]
mylist.append = (4)  # Wrong!!
```

`append` is a method that is used to add an element to an existing list object. If the object contains 3 elements and you wish to append a new element to it, you can do it as follows:

```
mylist.append(4)
```

There is something very important to note here. Whenever you do something like this:

```
mylist = []  # or mylist = list()
```

You are creating an object of type list. Hence, if you are familiar with OOP concepts, append is a member function of the class. To further verify this, you can do something like this: (Using Python 3.7)

```
>>> a = []
>>> type(a)
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: Can you also put the correct syntax?  Something like @Green Cell has done.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to programming!

Append is a (read-only) function. You don't *assign* to it, you *call* it.

```
mylist.append(4)
```

is what you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

append is a function so use mylist.append(4) and it should work fine.

Comment: no need to echo others response

Answer (score 0):

`append` is an attribute of List. If you want to append an item to your list use append as a function.

```py
mylist = [1, 2, 3]
mylist.append(4)

print(mylist)
>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

what you are currently doing it you are trying to override the `append` function to be = `4`

Answer (score -2):

append is function it takes the argument which you want to append:
e.g.

.append()

Comment: This has already been stated by other answers multiple times.